# ¿Cómo hacer sentencias preparadas en MySQL?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Resulta que ahora que me estoy metiendo en el mundillo del `php`, me gustaría hacer mas seguro mi código contra la inyección `sql`, ¿como podría transformar esto en una consulta preparada?

```
$id_user = $_SESSION['id'];
$querydata = "SELECT * FROM `nodes` WHERE id_ass='$id_user'";
$resultdata = mysqli_query($con, $querydata) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$rowdata = mysqli_fetch_array($resultdata);
$gen_name = $rowdata['genname'];
```

Un saludo :).

Ya tengo hecho el `$conn` pero no se como continuar.

Comment: Te recomiendo echar una mirada a esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php

Comment: Ya, he mirado pero no me acaba de quedar claro como extraigo los valores $gen_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He tomado tu ejemplo y he modificado, espero que te ayude.

```
$conn = new mysqli("mihost", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos");

$id_user = $_SESSION['id'];
$gen_name = '';

$querydata = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE id_ass=?"); // "?" este simbolo se utiliza para indicar el parametro a utilizar
$querydata->bind_param("s", $id_user ); //pasamos los parametros a utilizar, "s" por que es string o fecha || "i" en caso de ser entero
$querydata->execute();// ejecutamos
$querydata->bind_result($gen_name);// almacenamos
$querydata->fetch();// obtenemos

echo $gen_name; //mostramos resultado

$querydata->close();//cerramos la sentencia
```